# JDO Query for fetching data which contain null value for parentkey

Tags: google-app-engine, null, jdo

I want to retrieve data whose parent key is null

```
query = pm.newQuery(Question.class, "state==0");
query.setFilter("tier instanceof Tier");
query.setFilter("tier.id == null");
query.setClass(Question.class);
query.setOrdering("lastCustomerActivityTime");
questions = (List<Question>) query.execute();
```

I have written above code but it fetch all data including whose parent key is not null.
is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Strongly suggest you [read up on the JDO API and JDOQL](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1/jdo/jdoql.html). If you set the filter, it sets the filter (overwriting what was there). Nothing is magically appended to the end of what you had, and its illogical to expect it.